# Preserving Email Subject & Email Message from actual Template when sending via Custom Button in Salesforce

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to preserve the Email Subject & email Message that are defined on the Docusign Template and send those vs sending generic email subject & message when sending a document via Custom Button in Salesforce? Below is my button code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}

var DST='<Docusign Template Id>';
var LA='0';
var OSO = 'Send';
var CRL = 'Email~{!Fulfillment__c.Primary_Contact_Email__c};Role~Client;FirstName~   {!Fulfillment__c.Primary_Contact_First_Name__c};LastName~{!Fulfillment__c.Primary_Contact_Last_Name__c}';
var CCRM='Client~Client';

window.location.href = '/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID='+eSignatureNotSent.Id+'&DST='+DST+'&LA='+LA+'&CRL='+CRL+'&OCO='+OCO+'&CCRM='+CCRM;
```

I think Docusign is using Default Email Subject and Default Email Message defined in the Admin settings in Salesforce. I do not want to send it as all the work is done when building templates in Docusign.

Answer (score 2):

If you leave the Default Email Message blank in the Admin settings, it will grab the contents of the Template Email Message.

The API has a hard requirement to define an email subject through the request. Currently because Salesforce uses the API, it has to follow this guideline.

My best advice is making a custom button that defines the Email subject that you'd like for each workflow that you may have.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will test it, yes, that was my alternate approach to populate the subject & body for each workflow.